# Reading variable from another function Python

Tags: python

```
class Home(tk.Frame):
    readName = ""
    def canteenStallsNameOfUser(self,readName):
        self.readName = readName

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
       Label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome , " + self.readName)
```

I am passing a value to `canteenStallsNameOfUser` Function from another .py file and i want the `self.readName` in `__init__` function to show the value that I pass. How can I take the value from `readName` in canteenStallsNameOfUser function and display it in the `__init__` function?

Basically , I want the name of user to be displayed on the label.

I passed the value from another .py file using this after importing the class "Home":
Home.canteenStallsNameOfUser(Home,readNameOfUser)

Comment: `canteenStallsNameOfUser` cannot be called before `__init__`. You may need to pass the name directly to the `__init__` instead.

Comment: Please show the code how you create an instance of `Home` and how you call `canteenStallsNameOfUser()`. Also describe the behavior that your user should see on the screen. This description should include what text and buttons the user sees and not worry about variables and functions.

Comment: After a Login Page , the user will be directed to a Menu page and he will see his name on the Menu page.

The Login page has imported the canteenStalls.py and has a calling of function called : 
Home.canteenStallsNameOfUser(Home,readNameOfUser)

The above function calls the "canteenStallsNameOfUser" function in class "Home" in the Menu page and pass the name of User to the Menu page. I wishes to display it in the label which is in "__init__"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `readName` as a parameter to `__init__`:

```
class Home(tk.Frame):
     readName = ""
     def canteenStallsNameOfUser(self,readName):
         self.readName = readName

     def __init__(self, parent, controller, readName):
        self.readName = readName
        Label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome , " + self.readName)
```

Comment: *I am facing this error while trying to display it on the frame. I have this code to create the Frame:*

frame = Home(parent=container, controller=self,readName = "") 

*Error:*
invalid command name "58093080tick"
    while executing
"58093080tick"
    ("after" script)